# Sort lines with perl

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, grep

I have a file that looks like:

```
text text text text : 6 min
text text text text : 2 min
text text text text : 8 min
text text text text : 2 min
```

I need to sort this file to get that output :

```
text text text text : 2 min
text text text text : 2 min
text text text text : 6 min
text text text text : 8 min
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work :

```
my @copy = ();
open (INFILE, $ARGV[0]);
while (<INFILE>) {
push (@copy, $_);
}
my @lines = sort grep /^: (\d+) min/ , @copy;
print @lines;
```

Is there any easy way to do this in perl ?

Answer (score 8):

It is easier with `sort`:

```
$ sort -t: -k2 file
text text text text : 2 min
text text text text : 2 min
text text text text : 6 min
text text text text : 8 min
```

- `-t:` means "set the delimiter of columns as :"
- `-k2` means "filter on 2nd column", that is, just after the `:`.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably recommend the `sort` solution posted first, because it seems simplest. Here's a perl version, however. It is based on a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). This is not required, but for any larger files it is probably efficient, and it is somewhat tidy looking.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <>;    # read the input file
@lines = map $_->[1],
         sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
         map { my ($num) = /:\s*(\d+)/; [ $num, $_ ] } @lines;
print @lines;
```

The basic idea is this:

- Start with a `map` statement to extract the numbers, return a reference to a two-element array that contains that number, and the original line `[ $num, $_ ]`
- Sort the resulting list based on the first element.
- End with another `map` statement that turns our arrays back into the original lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong. You want:

```
/[^:]+: (\d+) min/
```

Also, can't you just do this?

```
@copy = <INFILE>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be perl (fedorquis suggestion is very good), this nugget should do it:

```
my @file=<>;
foreach (sort {(split(' ',$a))[5] <=> (split(' ',$b))[5]} @file) {print;}
```

Give the filename as parameter.

Comment: How about `-2` instead of `5`?

Comment: Works just as well. I'm just a traditionalist :)

Comment: You should use the default `' '` for split and not `/\s/`. The only reason to prefer `/\s+/` is if you don't want leading whitespace stripped. Also note that you are missing the quantifier `+`, which will lead to off-by-one errors if the input text contains consecutive whitespace.

Comment: Agreed on the first part and changed accordingly. I mildly disagree on the quantifier, but as we're already talking about fictional situations that haven't been described by the OP, I'll not defend myself on the quantifier issue.

Answer (score 1):

`my @lines = map { $_->[1] } sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0]}   map { [ /:\s(\d+)/, $_ ] } @copy`

How it works

starting at the right, the first map makes an array of arrays.  Each array element contains the number extracted from each line as it's first element and the whole line as the second element

Next the sort works on the first element of the array just set up using the so called ufo operator for numeric comparison

Finally, the last map extracts only the second elements, now in the correct order

This method is known as a "Schwartzian Transform" and is in the perldoc perlfaq4 section "How do I sort an array by (anything)?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Schwartzian transform** to sort lines on the basis of number like

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @lines = ("Test:2 min","Test:8 min","Test:6 min");
print Dumper(\@lines);

@lines = map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { [$_, /(\d+) min/] } @lines;

@lines = sort @lines;
print Dumper(\@lines);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Test:2 min',
          'Test:8 min',
          'Test:6 min'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'Test:2 min',
          'Test:6 min',
          'Test:8 min'
        ];
```